# Spring integration test for MVCConfig failing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I was *loosely* following the tutorial under: http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/ and can't seem to make my integration test for my MVCConfig pass.

It throws the following Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
```

Full stack trace here: http://pastebin.com/B3tWS3hH

I tried running the tests in the completed tutorial, and it also fails.

Integration Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MVCConfig.class)
public class RestDomainIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wac;

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void thatRestDomainCanBeAccessed() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

MVCConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.scrumster.rest.controller"})
public class MVCConfig { }
```

Am I missing anything? I searched some related questions, but can't seem to find anything that fits the bill.

Comment: Post the _full_ stacktrace.

Comment: Are you using `spring-boot`? If so, you need to have `@EnableAutoConfiguration` instead of `@EnableWebMvc`. If not, what do you have in `MVCConfig`?

Comment: @TheKojuEffect I don't completely understand, but my MVCConfig is empty. Because it's empty, does this mean I should use ``spring-boot``  and ``@EnableAutoConfiguration`` instead?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Added full stack trace.